# JSON.stringify() alternative and JSON2.js

Tags: jquery, json, stringify

I am trying to make a WCF call to a function which accepts one String parameter. When I pass parameters from jQuery, I am using JSON.stringify(parameters), where parameters is a name:value collection containing the parameters I want to pass.

My doubts are

1. In my version of IE, JSON is not defined. So, I used the JSON2.js library and included that in the master page of my site.
2. I still encounter the same message. JSON is undefined on IE.

Well, it works perfectly on Google Chrome.

PS - This is all on .NET.

Script name is `json2.js`. The values I am passing in jQuery are

```
data:JSON2.stringify(parameters),
contentType: "application/json2; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json2"
```

I am using IE8. (Sorry to not provide this detail before, just added)

Please advise.

Comment: ¿Which versions of IE are you using? It would help us to help you :) .

Comment: Which version of IE? Also, do you have an example page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `json2` at all places where you should ideally be using `json`

Please change your ajax call as

```
data:JSON.stringify(parameters),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json"
```

On an unrelated side-note, you can omit `charset` and `dataType` and change the call like this

```
data:JSON.stringify(parameters),
contentType: "application/json;",
```

Comment: Thanks Naveen, but I am still encountering the same issue. The following error message is displayed

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `JSON2.stringify(parameters)` you should use `JSON.stringify(parameters)`. Also make sure you have included the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) script to your site.

And if you are using IE8 you don't need json2.js at all as it natively supports `JSON.stringify` method.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I have added json2.js very well like I did for jQuery library. Somewhere, I am a little afraid why are the definitions not getting linked to json2.js library. I read on github.com, that this .js creates a property of JSON in the global object, and lets us use stringify and parse function. But this is not working here. Please advise.

Comment: I've noticed that you updated your question and stated that you are using IE8. If this is the case you don't need to reference any `json2.js` as IE8 natively supports the `JSON.stringify` method.

Comment: Well, I will need to make this application compatible for users working on browsers that don't have an implementation for JSON object.

Comment: I see, in this case you need to include it indeed.

Comment: Thanks Darin, with the suggestions mentioned here, the problem is solved, and I can make the WCF call properly.